# Facebook old API Video upload

Tags: facebook

Our application uploads video to facebook (using the REST API video.upload method). Everything was working fine, but nearly 10 hours ago we started to receive the error "This method must run on api-video.facebook.com".  We're already running it on api-video.facebook.com!  The url is http://api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=video.upload, it's hardcoded in the application, and never changed.  What's happening?  How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem right now.  This seems to be an issue on the Facebook side of the API.  Post in the forums, file a bug, raise a stink. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/

Comment: Yeah, the new API sucks so bad. I'm really disappointed by this little care Facebook is giving to its platform. Now to upload a photo you need a session-- you need to redirect to facebook.com just to come back with a session string so you can upload!
We ended up working with the two APIs: the new one for the authentication and the old one for things as the uploads.
And in the forums they're not giving responses.

But I guess that's how they will be rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Since Facebook doesn't seem to want to document this:

- the call is to https://api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php
- params:
- access_token=...
- method=video.upload

The rest of the params work as before.